# HiJavafx tableview scrollbar thickness by css

Tags: css, javafx-2, fxml

is it possible to customize TableView's default scrollbar (vertical one) make it thicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more intuitive way, but if you add extra padding to the sides of the increment and decrement buttons it will have the desired effect:

```
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button, 
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0.5em  ;
}
```

(The default css used 0.25em on all sides.)